# Attach file to email

Tags: 8, webforms, mimemail

I have a site with a webform, which when submitted sends an email. The form has a file upload which should then attach the file as an attachment to the email. I'm not getting any attachment.

I've created a hook for `hook_mail_alter` and tried hardcoding any attachment to be sent but every email i get has no attachment.

```
function my_module_mail_alter(&$message) {
  $file_content = file_get_contents('sites/default/files/tmp/test.pdf');
  $message["params"]["attachments"] = array(
    'filecontent' => $file_content,
    'filename' => 'test.pdf',
    'filemime' => 'application/pdf'
  );
}
```

I've debugged the `MailManager.php` just before the email is sent and the `$message` variables `param['attachement']` has the valid contents from the code above.

I've instaled modules: **SMTP** (so i can send emails from my local), **MimeMail** and enabled **MailSystem** The emails are being sent without any issue, but again never with an attachement.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, any ideas?

Core: 8.6

Comment: did you check `$file_content`  has the content, `'sites/default/files/tmp/test.pdf'` it may not the correct location ?

Comment: Try to install https://mailcatcher.me/ to work with mail in local, it support attachement.

Comment: Try with this it works for me , `$file = file_load($fid);
$message["params"]["attachments"][] =[
     'filepath' => $file->uri,
];`

Comment: Instead of attaching files to emails you better should just send a download link, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer, which is just an extension on the comment from @berramou

```
$file = file_load($fid);
  $message["params"]["attachments"][] =[
    'filepath' => $file->getFileUri(),
    'filemime' => '' // argument must be present, but can remain empty
  ];
}
```

Comment: Please create a ticket in the Webform issue queue so that we can add support for file attachments via SMTP and MimeMail.

Comment: @jrockowitz sure